# How to change the color of an interpolated string?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I want to have a user input values, which I will save into a string, and then interpolate that string into a console output. Is there a way to make that interpolated string change color. I am aware of using Console.Background/ForegroundColor, but, so far, those have changed the color of the entire output. 
Best help would be if there was some way to utilize code akin to

`Console.WriteLine($"This would be the {string}."`

and have {string} be a different color, but I will incorporate anything that works.

Comment: Have you considered using Console.Write() instead (no line break character at the end of each call) and just separating your string into separate calls?

Comment: use resetcolor after writing particular color text.......http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-color

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will do the trick for you

```
string letters = $"This would be the {string}."
string ColoredLetters = {string}; // Whatever is your string
Char[] array = letters.ToCharArray();
void WriteLineWithColoredLetter(string letters, char c) 
{
    var NormalWrite = letters.IndexOf(c);
    Console.Write(letters.Substring(0, NormalWrite));
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write(ColoredLetters);
    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.WriteLine(letters.Substring(NormalWrite + 1));
}
```